# How can I get NFC on my laptop working?

Tags: 16.04, ubuntu-gnome, nfc

My laptop (E7440) has nfc symbol engraved next to the fingerprint reader.
For some reason I am unable to use my fingerprint reader too...

If i enter `rfkill list`, i get in a list:

```
10: nfc0: NFC
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Meaning, some sort or form of NFC is detected.
When I enter `nfctool -l`, i get

```
nfc0:
          Tags: [ ]
          Devices: [ ]
          Protocols: [ Felica MIFARE Jewel ISO-DEP NFC-DEP ]
          Powered: No
          RF Mode: None
          lto: 150
          rw: 15
          miux: 2047
```

But I am unable to use it for anything with `nfctool -d nfc0 -***`
With `nfc-list`, I get

```
nfc-list uses libnfc 1.7.1
No NFC device found.
```

neard is running too.

Does anybody know, if there is something, I can do with NFC (login, run bash scripts or else useful) and how?

Comment: It may be that the contactless features are disabled by default. There are methods for enabling them here: https://blog.g3rt.nl/enable-dell-nfc-contactless-reader.html https://github.com/jacekkow/controlvault2-nfc-enable